Is there a way to use TableView with DataSet?
The following produces a result visually similar to a DataSet:
TableView[Headers -> {"cat", "dog"}]
However, trying TableView[myDataSet] doesn't work.
Is there an extremely simple way to make the DataSet editable like this?

Update 1: concrete example
as per @Bob Hanlon's request.
In my code it would be convenient to use a mathematica Dataset.
For example,
data = Dataset @ <|
   "Row1" -> <|"Column1" -> 1, "Column2" -> 2, "Column3" -> 3|>, 
   "Row2" -> <|"Column1" -> 4, "Column2" -> 5, "Column3" -> 6|>, 
   "Row3" -> <|"Column1" -> 7, "Column2" -> 8, "Column3" -> 9|>
   |>

When run in a notebook, this produces a grid that looks almost identical to the output of:
TableView[
 Headers -> {{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"}, {"Row1", "Row2", 
    "Row3"}}, AllowedDimensions -> {3, 3}]

To see what it looks like, here's a picture:

However, they are different. The Tableview version cannot be indexed like the Dataset can.
And the Dataset cannot be edited onscreen.
I've experimented a bit with passing values back and forth.
This seems to work for one direction:
TableView[data[Values][Values] // Normal, 
   Headers -> {
     {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"}, 
     {"Row1", "Row2","Row3"}}, 
   AllowedDimensions -> {3, 3}]

However this feels a bit clunky.
It would be nice to just have a Dataset, type values in, and use it.
Rather than having to manually type in ...-> <|"Column1" -> 1,... all the time.

Please provide a concrete example, i.e., a small sample of your data and the code that you try using.

If you have a simple, rectangular dataset, then you can first convert it to lists of lists with Normal: TableView[Normal[ds[Values]]].

Here is a very minimal code that works for plain, boring rectangular datasets without any funky stuff (like nesting or arbitrary symbolic content ...).
Clear[editDataset, toDataset]

editDataset[ds_Dataset] := Module[{data, columns, rows},
  data = Normal@ds[[Values, Values]];
  columns = Keys@First@Normal@ds;
  rows = Normal@Keys@ds;  
  TableView[data, Headers -> {columns, rows}]]

toDataset[TableView[data_, ___, Headers -> {cols_, rows_}, ___]] := 
 Dataset[Map[AssociationThread[cols, #] &, AssociationThread[rows -> data]]]

editDataset[ds]


You can now further enhance this to allow datasets without column/row names, make it dynamic etc.
